# What screws to use to attached tie-downs from shed roof rafters to top sill?

Tags: construction, shed

What screws should I  use to attached tie-downs from shed roof rafters to top sill?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the device(either nail or screw) recommended by the manufacturer.

Simpson H10 installs With sixteen 8D x 1-1/2" Nails

[image]